# Detect soft navigation bar on mobile device with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm looking for a way to detect soft navigation bar on a mobile device. Scrolling down hides the bar but initially it pushes down the page and it disturbs the UI. Checking `window.innerHeight` doesn't help, event listeners don't detect it and I'm really out of options. Hope you guys have some fresh ideas on this.